# Zend_Db_Select EXISTS

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-select

One part of my query is EXISTS condition:

```
$select->where(
  'EXISTS(' .
  'SELECT `price_property_id` FROM `property_price` ' .
    'WHERE `price_property_id` = `pu_property_id`' .
      ' AND `price_value` >= ' . $params['price_min'] .
      ' AND `price_value` <= ' . $params['price_max'] .
   ')'
);
```

How it writes in right way in Zend Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, `Zend_Db_Select` doesn't have specific methods to include subqueries in the `where` clause. I think you cannot improve it any further, the way it's written.

You might rewrite the subquery as an `OUTER JOIN`, and you'd be able to leverage some more `Zend_Db_Select` methods, but I'm not sure about the advantages of doing it, as far as your code is working and clear to read.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 2):

I create my sub queries and sub selects as new Zend_Db_Select objects. This make the code slightly cleaner as I can potentially reuse that query elsewhere, it also helps with debugging as I can `echo (string)$subQuery` to review just that part of the SQL.

```
$subQuery = new Zend_Db_Select();
$subQuery->from(array('price' => 'property_price'))
     ->where('price_property_id = pu_property_id')
     ->where('price_value >= ?', $params['price_min'])
     ->where('price_value <= ?', $params['price_max']);

$select->where('EXISTS('.$subQuery.')');
```

Comment: `$select->where('EXISTS('.$subQuery.')');` is failing because $subQuery is not a string (in ZF2 at least)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for!:

```
<?php

// $select is instance of Zend_Db_Select
// $db is instance of Zend_Db_Adapter

$select->where('exists (?)', new Zend_Db_Expr(
    $db->quoteInto('select * from your_table where id = ?', $id, Zend_Db::PARAM_INT)
));

?>
```